# How to make sprite moving forward continuously in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Need your help again.

I am currently working on my first iPhone game. In my game i want my car to move forward continuously. I also want my background which is a road, of course, to give the like it is moving.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using the Parallax in Cocos2D. Here is a video tutorial on how to do that [Parallax Scrolling with Cocos2D](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FFtKnBDFv0).

Here is another great site with many free tutorials on how to accomplish many things with Cocos2D that will most likely be very helpful to you [Cocos2D Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

I would also highly recommend the top 3 books in the following list on amazon [Cocos2D game programming books](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_scat_15375251_ln?rh=n:15375251,k%3acocos2d&keywords=cocos2d&ie=UTF8&qid=1316030662&scn=15375251&h=775f06e192d6bcf56081837d0bddc4cb972c5dc5)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark the answer that was the most helpfull as the answer and vote up any answers/comments that were helpfull as well. Good Luck with Cocos2D!

Answer (score 1):

That's not a lot of information to work with. To do the basics of what you are asking for, the car wouldn't actually move it all. It would just stay in the middle of the screen while the background moves. You can just create a [scrolling parallax background](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4883).